# Permutation Sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Someone can explain me  how Permutation on SymPy works I have already read the documentation but  I didn't understand what Permutation is doing, for example if  write:

```
a = Permutation([1,0,2])
```

What this function is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, [a permutation on n symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) is a way to express a re-ordering of those n symbols.

Writing `a = Permutation([1,0,2])` defines a permutation on 3 symbols, where the symbols are `0`,`1`,`2` such that the first two elements will be swapped(we call [that transposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Transpositions)), and the last element will be a [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) (meaning it will not change its position).

Here's an example of using your permutation and applying it to a list of numbers to see how it acts on it.

```py
from sympy import * 
from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation
from sympy.interactive import init_printing
init_printing(perm_cyclic=False, pretty_print=True)
p = Permutation([1,0,2])
display(p)

A = [3,4,5]
Ap = p(A)
display(Ap)
```

The result of this snippet is:

[image]

(you see the long form of the permutation first, and then the result of applying the permutation to the list)

You can see, at the end, the list `A=[3,4,5]` was permuted by the permutation `p` into the list `[4,3,5]`.